# Error after installing Django (supposed PATH or PYTHONPATH "error")

Tags: django, 64-bit, installation, ubuntu-10.04

I guess this is a PATH/PYTHONPATH error, but my attempts failed so far to make django working.

System is Ubuntu 10.04, 64bit:

```
mx:~/webapps$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=lucid
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.04 LTS"
```

Python version: 2.6.5:

```
@mx:~/webapps$ python -V
Python 2.6.5
```

When I run django-admin.py, the following happens:

```
mx:~/webapps$ django-admin.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core import management
ImportError: No module named django.core
```

Similar when I import django in python shell:

```
mx:~/webapps$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56)
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django
>>> quit()
```

More details:

```
mx:~/webapps$ python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print get_python_lib()"

/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
```

Within python shell:

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56)
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/bin', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django', '/home/petra/webapps', '/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6']
```

django-admin.py can be found here:

```
mx:~/webapps$ locate django-admin.py
~/install/sources/Django-1.2.1/build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/django/bin/django-admin.py
~/install/sources/Django-1.2.1/build/scripts-2.6/django-admin.py
~/install/sources/Django-1.2.1/django/bin/django-admin.py
/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/bin/django-admin.pyc
```

and in the end this doesn't help:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django:$PYTHONPATH"
```

nor this:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django:$PYTHONPATH"
```

How to solve this !?

Thanks all in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending hours and hours in CLI :) I have finally found the solution. The reason django-admin.py wasn't able to execute was access permission of the /usr/local/lib directory, actually,lack of owner's execute permission.

So, one: `sudo chmod 711 /usr/local/lib` solves the django-admin.py execution problem for ever :)

Answer (score 2):

You python path seems to be screwed up.

If you want to import `module` in Python, then the *path to module* must be in `sys.path`. For instance if you want to import a module located at

```
/long/path/to/module
```

then you must have

```
/long/path/to
```

in the `sys.path`, and *not* `/long/path/to/module`!

Since you django install seems to be installed in `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages`, then the following should fix your problem:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages:$PYTHONPATH"
```

That doesn't explain why you did not have that path in `sys.path` in the first place, though...

Comment: I had a typo. I fixed it and added explanations of why I believe this should work.

Comment: Its works for me... ""/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:$PYTHONPATH"" thankx man